# How do you swap first half of an array with second half with an unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, string, swap

I am trying to swap the first half of an array of some string obtained by the user with the second half without knowing the size of the array. Here is my attempt.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int size;

char string1[size]; 
char *string1Ptr;

cout << "Please enter a string: ";
cin.getline(string1, size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    string1Ptr = &string1[i];
    int n = 0;
    if(*string1Ptr == '\0') {
        n = i / 2;
        strcpy(string1, string1+n);
        strcat(string1, string1);
    }
}

cout << string1 << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any issues with your current solution?

Comment: Is this an assignment? Because you can do it in two lines of code if you use `std::string` instead of raw arrays.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So you leave a comment even more unclear? If you want more detail, just tell him what you want to know. If you think the question is unsavable, vtc. If you think the question is bad, downvote. Your comment just never makes sense. (Yeah, I should probably have flagged it instead of having this discussion, that is my mistake.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen The problem, and presumably the reason this was closed, is that there is no actual, answerable question. The title is grammatically a question, but it's not an answerable question and doesn't relate to the body in any obvious way. I was hoping the question could be saved by the OP just asking a question at the end, like "Why does this code X and not Y?" or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this might be homework, this is a great chance to learn the standard library. What you are doing is just a simple rotation, and there is an [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) for that:

```
std::rotate(string1, string1 + std::strlen(string1) / 2,
            string1 + std::strlen(string1));
```

does all you need, throw away your error prone loops!

Also you should use `const int size = somesize` or better `std::string` instead of `char[]`. If you use the latter, use `std::string::size` instead of `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

Use *strlen(string1)* to find the length of the variable *string1*.

Maybe you should consider using c++ features to do the work you want.

Using *std::string* class would be more flexible than the *char array* method since it can read any number of character and it is not delimited by the *size* variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  string string1;
  getline(cin, string1); // Here, string 1 contains all the characters until a newline character is found.

  // Get the string length
  int n = string1.length();

  // Swaps the first half with the second half.
  string swapped_string = string1.substr(n/2, n/2 + 1) + string1.substr(0, n/2);

  cout << swapped_string << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are a few problems with your code snippet that you may not have considered.

1. Variable *size* is not initialized.
2. You can't define a fixed size array with a non-const variable. (*char string1[size]*)
3. *strcpy()* will copy beyond the allocated memory for *string1* if *(strlen(string1) > size/2)* resulting in a buffer overflow.
4. You should use the statement *break;* to terminate the *for()* loop when you enter your *if()* statement because you then are done swapping the first half with the second half of the array.